# Kubuntu 21, multiple monitors, task switching: limit to one monitor

Tags: kubuntu

I have three monitors, the center is the primary. The task switcher appears on the monitor with the active window, but I want it to show ONLY on the primary monitor, always, no exceptions. Is that even possible? Something I can change in the QML file maybe?

Comment: I was not aware. I have upgraded to 20.04, am in the process of upgrading to 20.1, then will go most current. We'll see if it's still an issue - though I suspect it will be. Hope not.

Comment: FYI:  It's not 20.1 but 20.10 (ie. 2020-October release).  Ubuntu uses *year.month* format for all *deb* based systems, and *year* for *snap* only systems (eg. Ubuntu Core 20 which is *snap* only).   There is no Kubuntu 21; as Kubuntu is a desktop and the team only produce *deb* based system thus 21.04 is their latest  (only GNOME is packaged to run on *snap* only releases)